# python lxml xpath error: invalid expression when using '//'

Tags: python, xml, xpath, find, lxml

I am new to lxml and XPath. I am trying to find an element by text, and couldn't get it to work. Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: I tested with different XML files, one with 1,262,297 lines works, the other with 7,594,023 lines does not work. Am I running into some inherent limitation of XPath/lxml? Or is the file corrupted in some way?

The xPath expression:

```
for e in root.xpath('//d[text()="abc"]'):
   print(e.text)
```

The error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/myXMLprocessor.py", line 32, in func01
    for e in root.xpath('//d[text()="abc"]'):
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1577, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

My xml file is a 7594023 line file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xxx SYSTEM "http://xxx">
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <d foo="bar">abc</d>
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    ..etc..
  </b>
</a>
```

The basic code

```
from lxml import etree as ET 
import os
filename = os.fsdecode("my.xml")
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
for e in root.xpath('//d[text()="abc"]'):
   print(e.text)
```

I have tried virtually any variation of the above I could think of.. Then I tried a direct search, like the one below. That worked. But then I replaced it with a search at all depths ('//'), but that failed with the error above.. What am I doing wrong?

The direct search (which worked):

```
for e in root.xpath('/a/b/c/d[text()="abc"]'):
   print(e.text)
```

The search at any depth (which did not work):

```
for e in root.xpath('//d[text()="abc"]'):
   print(e.text)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: can't reproduce the problem. for me both the code snippets work

Comment: Weird... Can it be a version issue? I am running Python 3.6.9. I do not know how to retrieve the XPath version... Can it be an encoding or doctype issue? I forgot to mention the latter and now included it in the above.

Comment: I dont think this is a version issue, your code works in Py2.7.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue to the xml file, see above.